# Improving Primefaces DataTable Performance

Tags: java, sql, jsf, jpa, primefaces

I was wondering if there is a way to enhance the dataTable’s performance.

Here is my scenario:

My application has lots of dataTables displaying data from some really huge tables from the database (I’m talking about tables with millions of rows), and they also have lots of relationships with other tables, so I need to be very careful loading data from them, otherwise my application will get pretty slow.

My first step was to implement a lazyDataModel, so the dataTable can load only the data that is being displayed in the current page, of course it wasn’t an option not to do this, the dataTable wouldn’t even load if I tried to bring all the data, but even with the lazy loading it was taking some seconds to load.

In order to reduce the loading time a little more, I had to bring only the columns that are being used by the dataTable, so instead of writing a query like this:

```
SELECT t FROM Table t
```

I write this one:

```
SELECT t.column1, t.column2, t.column3, t.column4  FROM Table t
//The four columns are only ones that are being displayed on the dataTable.
```

The performance was significantly increased by doing this, now the data is loading fast enough, it is just taking some milliseconds to load.

Here is my lazyDataModel:

```
public class MyLazyDataModel<T> extends LazyDataModel<T> implements Serializable {

  @Override
  public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
       DataTable dt = (DataTable) UIViewRoot.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
       String whereClause = getfilters(filters);

       //Load the data
       List data = loadData("SELECT "+columns(dt)+" FROM "+ entity()+ " t WHERE "+ whereClause, first, pageSize);

       //Set the row count
       setRowCount(loadData("SELECT COUNT(t) FROM "+ entity()+ " t WHERE "+ whereClause));

       return data;
  }

  ...                
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine, but there is still one problem:

Although the data is being loaded within a few milliseconds, I still have to execute another query to set the row count, and this one is still taking several seconds to return the result, I’ve tried not to set it, but the dataTable didn’t displayed any data.

I've measured the time taken to set the row count, and the result was 5438 ms, I don't think it is worth to spend this much time just to set this value. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to improve this?

I'm using Primefaces 3.4.1, JSF and JPA2.

Comment: Analyze your query would be my first suggestion, make sure that the columns you are searching have proper indexes. Don't use to much functions in your where clause.

Comment: Adjust the sample, to difference where you limit the returns value. In the example, the `Select count` result is equals to `data.size()`.

Comment: The problem goes beyond your web application. Your query needs to be analyzed; there may be some denormalization necessary here. The point is that there's no magic bullet you'll stick in the presentation tier that's going to make your data layer issues disappear

Comment: @kolossus I agree with you, it will be better to solve this on the data layer, I'll keep looking for a solution, thanks for the answer!

Comment: I think a native SQL query could help

Answer (score 0):

Try to count *just* the primary key:

```
setRowCount(loadData("SELECT COUNT(t."+entityPkFieldName()+") FROM "+ entity()+ " t WHERE "+ whereClause));
```

Of course, you need the Pk field name.

Good luck!

Comment: It didn't make much difference.